# MSBuild fails to copy dlls from relative path

Tags: msbuild, relative-path

Solution Directory contains ExtraDlls And Project Directories.
In the Project.csproj file we have references of dlls in the ExtraDlls with relative path. The Dlls in the ExtraDlls directory are always available.

```
<Reference Include="xyx, Version=7.3.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=<sometoken>">
      <SpecificVersion>False</SpecificVersion>
      <HintPath>..\ExtraDlls\A.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
<Reference Include="xyz, Version=7.4.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=<sometoken>">
      <SpecificVersion>False</SpecificVersion>
      <HintPath>..\ExtraDlls\B.dll</HintPath>
      <Private>True</Private>
    </Reference>
```

Using below batch file to publish web project. But it fails with below mentioned details.

```
SET MSBUILD_PATH="C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\MSBuild\Current\\Bin"
SET PUBLISH_DIRECTORY="C:\publish\ProjectA"
SET PROJECT_DIR="C:\SolutionDir\ProjectDir"
SET PROJECT="C:\SolutionDir\ProjectDir\Project.csproj"
cd %PROJECT_DIR%

%MSBUILD_PATH%\MSBuild.exe %PROJECT%  /p:DeployOnBuild=True /p:DeployDefaultTarget=WebPublish /p:WebPublishMethod=FileSystem /p:DeleteExistingFiles=True /p:publishUrl=%PUBLISH_DIRECTORY%

PreBuildEvent:

        copy "..\ExtraDlls\A.dll" "C:\SolutionDir\ProjectDir\bin\"
        copy "..\ExtraDlls\B.dll" "C:\SolutionDir\ProjectDir\bin\"

  The system cannot find the path specified.
  The system cannot find the path specified.

C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\MSBuild\Current\Bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(1328,5): error MSB3073:       copy "..\ExtraDlls\A.dll" "C:\SolutionDir\ProjectDir\bin\" [C:\SolutionDir\ProjectDir\Project.csproj]

C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\MSBuild\Current\Bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(1328,5): error MSB3073:       copy "..\ExtraDlls\B.dll" "C:\SolutionDir\ProjectDir\bin\" [C:\SolutionDir\ProjectDir\Project.csproj]

C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\MSBuild\Current\Bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(1328,5): error MSB3073:     " exited with code 1.
```

Already tried with changing root directory in batch file. i.e. when root directory set with one containing MSBuild.exe, still getting the same issue.

Setting References updated with $(SolutionDir) didn't help.
e.g. $(SolutionDir)..\ExtraDlls\B.dll

There are many more references from ExtraDlls but showing error only for above two. Tried with changing relative path to absolute path in project.csproj file but still same error. So looks like it is being referenced from somewhere else.

Comment: It works very well while publishing web application manually using VS but error is while using MSBuild using command prompt.

Comment: Tried by using publish profile created using Visual Studio but it fails with same above errors: <br/> MSBuild "Full path of .csproj" /p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:PublishProfile="publish.pubxml"

Comment: You wrote **There are many more references from ExtraDlls**, so probably the problem is not in the **relative path** but in the specific these two `dll`s. What can you tell us about them?

Comment: Try changing `copy "..\ExtraDlls\A.dll" "C:\SolutionDir\ProjectDir\bin\"` to `copy "ExtraDlls\A.dll" "C:\SolutionDir\ProjectDir\bin\"`.

Comment: @Baruch Yea, there are many references, but in the PreBuildEvent Copy dll code is added just for two Dlls which was failing. I think it was throwing error in the PreBuildEvent and so it was not going further.

Comment: @LanceLi-MSFT:  It worked after passing SolutionDir property in the command: MSBuild /Property:SolutionDir=%SOL_DIR_PATH%

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the project.csproj file, in the PreBuildEvent section the code is added if SolutionDir is not available then use ..\ (which visual studio can understand I guess) but MSBuild was throwing error or actually checking path starting with .\ which doesn't exist.

While using MSBuild.exe command pass a property /Property:SolutionDir="Path to solution file directory" which resolves all references and now getting all ExtraDlls copied correctly.

e.g.

```
MSBuild /Property:SolutionDir=%SOL_DIR_PATH% %PROJECT_SLN_PATH%\%PROJECT_DIRECTORY_NAME%\%PROJECT_NAME%  /p:DeployOnBuild=True /p:DeployDefaultTarget=WebPublish /p:WebPublishMethod=FileSystem /p:DeleteExistingFiles=True /p:publishUrl=%PUBLISH_DIRECTORY%\%PROJECT_DIRECTORY_NAME%
```